# In Android Oreo, how to disconnect a connected BluetoothDevice, when my device is the advertiser

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have been dependant on Android's BluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertising to  disconnect all BLE connections. However, in Oreo, this call does not disconnect the devices anymore. Furthermore, even if I close the app, the bluetooth connection still stays up. This is not the expected behaviour.

It seems there are some bluetooth issues in Oreo: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/phone-by-google/iJeDphsoOJ4/FzR9f2w_BwAJ These might be related?

I dont see anything new in the API-s that might be related to this: https://blog.bluetooth.com/what-bluetooth-developers-should-know-about-android-o

How in Android Oreo can I disconnect from a connected device when my device is the one advertising and accepting connections?